# Dashboard component Lightning Homepage

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, analytics, home-page-component

Is there a way to display Dashboards on the lightning homepage?

I only see Report(charts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, the only way to get something like this done is to create a custom component with your dashboard in it and put it on the lightning homepage.

However, you can ofcourse drag multiple repport(chart) components into your homescreen and create your dashboard that way.

Comment: Thanks i realized in the previous Lightning limitations they do mention not being able to do that. However, in the winter 17 release there was no mention of any Dashboard limitations so i assumed it was fixed.

Comment: do we have this feature released in winter 17.....I would like to know how to add dashboards in lighening experience...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do with "lightning App builder". create your dashboard component in lightning and add them on lightning experience home page there.

Comment: Dashboard doesn't show up in the list of available components. I have it saved it in a public folder as well. Only Reports show up

Answer (score 0):

By now (May '18) the Dashboard Standard Lightning Component is available when editing a **Lightning Home Page**.

For **Lightning Record pages** it is **not** available.